# Dropdown selector in selenium Automation

Tags: selenium, automation

Hi I did a script to login github.com and dropdown then I need to select sign out option from drop down. I tried with **class** name and **xpath** both were not working.

**Code for select drop down menu.**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/header/div[7]/details/summary/span[2]")).click();
```

**Code for selecting signout option in dropdown menu**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/header/div[7]/details/summary/span[2]")).click();
```

Till dropdown menu it was working later selecting in drop down menu was not working.

Answer (score 0):

> driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/header/div[7]/details/summary/span[2]")).click();

The element you are referring is not belongs to <kbd>Sign out</kbd> button. Please use any one of the elements.

```
driver.findElement(By.xPath("//button[@class='dropdown-item dropdown-signout']")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[class*='dropdown-item dropdown-signout'")).click();
```

The class name of <kbd>Sign out</kbd> button is compound class name so you cannot directly use with `By.className`. Compound class names are not permitted in selenium if you use then you will experience the `CompoundClassException`

Answer (score 0):

instead of using class names you can use specific text such as "Sign out".
then your code for the clicking sign out button could be like :

```
driver.findElement(By.xPath("//button[contains(text(),'Sign out')]")).click();
```